# How to figure out why is the cursor failing in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a store procedure that will simply clone records. To clone records, I simply select a data set from the source and insert it into the same table with little changes using a loop.

I need to use loop here because I would have to check for all foreign records as well and clone them so I can't do everything in one select.

Here is my stored procedure

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN Question;

    DECLARE questionCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
     id
    ,title
    ,sort
    ,is_required
    ,controls_repeat_type
    ,controls_repeat_max
    ,view_type
    ,sort_controls_by
    ,sort_controls_direction
    ,max_controls
    ,visible_by_default
    ,visibility_condition
    ,visibility_condition_meta
    ,description
    ,status
    FROM survey_questions
    WHERE page_id = @sourcePageId;

    OPEN questionCursor;

    WHILE @fetchStatus = 0
    BEGIN

        FETCH NEXT FROM questionCursor 
        INTO 
          @questionId
        , @questionTitle
        , @questionSort
        , @questionIsRequired
        , @questionControlsRepeatType
        , @questionControlsRepeatMax
        , @questionViewType
        , @questionSortControlsBy
        , @questionSortControlsDirection
        , @questionMaxControls
        , @questionVisibileByDefault
        , @questionVisibilityCondition
        , @questionVisibilityConditionMeta
        , @questionDescription
        , @questionStatus

        -- Insert One Page At A Time
        INSERT INTO survey_questions(
         page_id
        ,survey_id
        ,title
        ,sort
        ,is_required
        ,controls_repeat_type
        ,controls_repeat_max
        ,view_type
        ,sort_controls_by
        ,sort_controls_direction
        ,max_controls
        ,visible_by_default
        ,visibility_condition
        ,visibility_condition_meta
        ,description
        ,status
        ,old_id)
        VALUES(@currentPageId
        ,@newSurveyId
        ,@questionTitle
        ,@questionSort
        ,@questionIsRequired
        ,@questionControlsRepeatType
        ,@questionControlsRepeatMax
        ,@questionViewType
        ,@questionSortControlsBy
        ,@questionSortControlsDirection
        ,@questionMaxControls
        ,@questionVisibileByDefault
        ,@questionVisibilityCondition
        ,@questionVisibilityConditionMeta
        ,@questionDescription
        ,@questionStatus
        ,@questionId);

        SET @lastQuestionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        SET @fetchStatus =  (SELECT TOP 1 fetch_status FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors (@@SPID | 0 ) WHERE name = 'questionCursor');

        SELECT 'FETCH STATUS => ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fetchStatus);;

        IF @fetchStatus <> 0
            BREAK;

    END; 

    CLOSE questionCursor;
    DEALLOCATE questionCursor;
    COMMIT TRAN Question;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();

    ROLLBACK TRAN Question;
END CATCH;
```

The problem is that the variable `@fetchStatus` return -1. According to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226062%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) -1 means...

> -1    FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.

But how can I find out what is causing it to fail?

The loop seems to be inserting one records into `survey_questions` table and then the status return -1.

Comment: Post your cursor code.

Comment: @mxix I have been trying since I posted the question I guess the close was too long and I was getting an error with no explanation. I just posted my code with no declaration to reduce the length

Comment: start by doing an initial FETCH outside the WHILE

Comment: Why are you using a cursor in the first place? This looks like simple insert statement to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow the logic posted here:
[sql-server-cursor-example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/)

```
DECLARE statements - Declare variables used in the code block
SET\SELECT statements - Initialize the variables to a specific value
DECLARE CURSOR statement - Populate the cursor with values that will be evaluated
NOTE - There are an equal number of variables in the DECLARE CURSOR FOR statement as there are in the SELECT statement.  This could be 1 or many variables and associated columns.
OPEN statement - Open the cursor to begin data processing
FETCH NEXT statements - Assign the specific values from the cursor to the variables
NOTE - This logic is used for the initial population before the WHILE statement and then again during each loop in the process as a portion of the WHILE statement
WHILE statement - Condition to begin and continue data processing
BEGIN...END statement - Start and end of the code block
NOTE - Based on the data processing multiple BEGIN...END statements can be used
Data processing - In this example, this logic is to backup a database to a specific path and file name, but this could be just about any DML or administrative logic
CLOSE statement - Releases the current data and associated locks, but permits the cursor to be re-opened
DEALLOCATE statement - Destroys the cursor
```

You are not doing the initial FETCH.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the standard way to use cursors.  It will work.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRAN Question;

  DECLARE questionCursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT id ,title ,sort ,is_required ,controls_repeat_type ,controls_repeat_max ,view_type ,sort_controls_by ,sort_controls_direction ,max_controls ,visible_by_default ,visibility_condition ,visibility_condition_meta ,description ,status FROM survey_questions
  WHERE page_id = @sourcePageId;

  OPEN questionCursor;

  FETCH NEXT FROM questionCursor 
  INTO @questionId , @questionTitle , @questionSort , @questionIsRequired , @questionControlsRepeatType , @questionControlsRepeatMax , @questionViewType , @questionSortControlsBy , @questionSortControlsDirection , @questionMaxControls , @questionVisibileByDefault , @questionVisibilityCondition , @questionVisibilityConditionMeta , @questionDescription , @questionStatus

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

    -- Insert One Page At A Time
    INSERT INTO survey_questions(page_id ,survey_id ,title ,sort ,is_required ,controls_repeat_type ,controls_repeat_max ,view_type ,sort_controls_by ,sort_controls_direction ,max_controls ,visible_by_default ,visibility_condition ,visibility_condition_meta ,description ,status ,old_id) 
      VALUES(@currentPageId ,@newSurveyId ,@questionTitle ,@questionSort ,@questionIsRequired ,@questionControlsRepeatType ,@questionControlsRepeatMax ,@questionViewType ,@questionSortControlsBy ,@questionSortControlsDirection ,@questionMaxControls ,@questionVisibileByDefault ,@questionVisibilityCondition ,@questionVisibilityConditionMeta ,@questionDescription ,@questionStatus ,@questionId); SET @lastQuestionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    FETCH NEXT FROM questionCursor 
    INTO @questionId , @questionTitle , @questionSort , @questionIsRequired , @questionControlsRepeatType , @questionControlsRepeatMax , @questionViewType , @questionSortControlsBy , @questionSortControlsDirection , @questionMaxControls , @questionVisibileByDefault , @questionVisibilityCondition , @questionVisibilityConditionMeta , @questionDescription , @questionStatus

  END; 

  CLOSE questionCursor;
  DEALLOCATE questionCursor;
  COMMIT TRAN Question;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();

  ROLLBACK TRAN Question;
END CATCH;
```